# Is "print this book for me double-sided and coil bind it" OK?

Tags: sentence-request

I want to ask a friend to print a PDF file for me on both sides of the page and then bind it with a metal coil at one edge. Can I say the following?

> Please print this book for me double-sided and coil bind it.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence sounds fine and would be readily understood.

You could optionally rephrase it as:

> Please print this book double-sided and coil bind it for me.

But since you are *asking* a friend and not *instructing* someone to do something, I would phrase your request as a question to be more polite:

> Could you print this book double-sided and coil bind it for me please?

In my opinion, I personally prefer to place the 'please' at the *end* of the sentence, so that it is the last word that the person hears, ensuring that you appear well-mannered.

Answer (score 1):

The type of binding you want is often called *spiral binding* (I've never heard *coil binding* but it might be common in other areas).

[image]

As Lee Mac suggests, your sentence sounds a bit like an *order* instead of a *request*.  It never hurts to say "please".

> **Could you please** double-side print this book and have it **spiral bound**? Thanks!

Comment: I believe coil binding & spiral binding are synonymous ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_binding))